# How to catch and change error message from webpack-dev-server?

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, localhost

We have an Angular 15 project where we have two files in our index.html that is loaded from another angular project. One css-file and one script-file. When deployed on server these files are available correctly in the right place. But when running localy we have then added a proxy.config to reroute the path of the files to the other angular project. So when both are started along side each other localy the main project are able to find the files.

Our problem is that sometimes you do not want to run both projects at the same time, since you dont need to see those two files in the other project. But we then get an error saying they can't be found like expected but, we would like to catch this error and change the message to saying something more useful. Like "We could not load the file "NAME" since you are not running "Project B". Is this possible?

I've seen that there is an onerror attribute for script-tags but can't find the same for the link-tag for the css-file. So I'm stuck on how to solve this.